# python-requests making a GET instead of POST request

Tags: python, nginx, python-requests, uwsgi, http-status-code-405

I have a daily cron which handles some of the recurring events at my app, and from time to time I notice one weird error that pops up in logs. The cron, among other things, does a validation of some codes, and it uses the webapp running on the same server, so the validation request is made via `POST` request with some data.

```
url = 'https://example.com/validate/'
payload = {'pin': pin, 'sku': sku, 'phone': phone, 'AR': True}
validation_post = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

So, this makes the actual request and I log the response. From time to time, and recently up to 50% of the request, the response contains the following message from nginx:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The method GET is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

So, the actual request was made using the *GET* method, not the *POST* as it was instructed in the code. In the nginx `access.log` I can see that entry:

```
123.123.123.123 - - [18/Feb/2015:12:26:50 -0500] "GET /validate/ HTTP/1.1" 405 182 "-" "python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-37-generic"
```

And the uwsgi log for the app shows the similar thing:

```
[pid: 6888|app: 0|req: 1589/58763] 123.123.123.123 () {40 vars in 613 bytes} [Mon Apr  6 11:42:41 2015] GET /validate/ => generated 182 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 405) 4 headers in 234 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

So, everything points out that the actual request was not made using the *POST*. The app route that handles this code is simple, and this is an excerpt:
@app.route('/validate/', methods=['POST'])
@login_required

```
def validate():
    if isinstance(current_user.user, Sales):
        try:
            #do the stuff here
        except Exception, e:
            app.logger.exception(str(e))
            return 0
    abort(403)
```

The app route can fail, and there are some `returns` inside the `try` block, but even if those fails or there is an expcetion, there is nothing that could raise the `405` error code in this block, only `403` which rarely happens since I construct and login the user manually from the cron.

I have found similar thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149181/python-requests-post-doing-a-get) but the soultion there was that there was a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS version, and I also have that redirect present in the server, but the URL the request is being made has the HTTPS in it, so I doubt this is the cause.

The stack I am running this on is `uwsgi`+`nginx`+`flask`. Can anyone see what might be causing this? To repeat, its not happening always, so sometimes its working as expected, sometimes not. I recently migrated from `apache` and `mod_wsgi` to this new stack and from that point I have started encontering this error; can't recally ever seeing it on `apache` environment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The only time we ever change a `POST` request to a `GET` is when we're handling a redirect. Depending on the redirect code, we will change the request method. If you want to be sure that we don't follow redirects, you need to pass `allow_redirects=False`. That said, you need to figure out why your application is generating redirects (including if it's redirecting to HTTP or to a different domain, or using a specific status code).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have modified the calls in my app with this flag and added some debugging info to try and see what is causing this.

Comment: I know it seems annoying that this is happening, but I want to assure you that what we're doing is the current best practice for handling redirects. What happems in requests is for your safety.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's by design, but removing the forward slash at the end of the URL fixed it for me:

```
url = 'https://example.com/validate/'  # remove the slash
payload = {'pin': pin, 'sku': sku, 'phone': phone, 'AR': True}
validation_post = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```