# Python Requests library post interpreted by Django as GET for some reason

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I'm trying to make a post request to our app's api for some regression testing, but for some reason when I make the request like so through requests, it's logged and interpreted as a GET request.

CODE:

```py
requests.post({HTTP_PROTOCOL}://{APP_URL}/api/route/',
              headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token},
              json=DATA)
```

LOG:

```
[Thu Jul 11 19:17:30 2019] GET /api/route/ => generated 2 bytes in 64 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 5 headers in 162 bytes (1 switches on core 1)
```

When I make the request through Postman, however, the request works totally fine and comes back with the created object in JSON, and in the logs it's recorded as a POST.

The backend is currently written in Django, using Django Rest Framework for the REST API. Here is the Route in our `urls.py` file:

```
url(r"^api/route/$", DataListView.as_view())
```

And I know that the `DataListView` works, because Postman works totally fine with it.

I've had similar problems where it wouldn't work because I was posting to a route without the slash, and that's not the case here. I know I'm posting to the route with the trailing slash, as you can see for yourselves.

QUESTION: How do I get this to work? And why would it be working in Postman, but not using the `requests` library?

EDIT 1:
Here's the headers in the request if that gives any clues:

```
{
    'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.22.0',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <access-token>'
}
```

EDIT 2:
I just did this:

```
print(resp.request.method)
```

and it printed out `GET`... No idea why. When I did it do my local server though, it printed out `POST`. Could it have something to do with the fact that I'm posting to a `https://` URL? This is bizzare.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149181/python-requests-post-doing-a-get), it looks like maybe it's getting a 301 or 302 redirect that's causing this.

Comment: Does your python code do something silly like monkeypatch the `requests.post` method?  i.e. `requests.post = requests.get`?

Comment: No. In fact, it only happens when I'm posting to our staging server. When I post to my local machine it works fine.

Comment: Is the `GET` request the only line that shows up in the access log?  i.e. perhaps it does a `POST` and then a `GET`, with a bunch of debugging crud in between, so you only see the `GET`?

Comment: Perhaps... but I don't think so. The JSON response that comes back is the response that should be coming back from the `GET` call. In this case, an empty list because there's nothing there.

Comment: Can you edit the view code to add a unique log message when the method is `POST`?

Comment: I just posted some more clarification about some stuff I found while looking around.

Comment: Is there a server in between, like nginx or something else, that tampers the request ?

Comment: Do you see the 301/302 redirects in the log?

Comment: There is nginx in the middle, and no I'm not seeing any 301's or 302's in the log.

Answer (score 5):

I ended up doing what @IanStapletonCordasco suggests for debugging in the question that I linked to and found out my `HTTP_PROTOCOL` was being set to `"http"` instead of `"https"`, which would result in a proxy redirect from *nginx* that was changing the `POST` to a `GET`. I changed that in my config file where that variable is set, and it worked.

Something else to note, for people that are having a similar problem, look at the URL you're posting to. If you have strict trailing slash checking turned on in Django (which I'm pretty sure is on by default), and you're posting to a URL without the trailing slash, it'll come back with a 30x redirect response that will cause a similar thing to happen. Try adding the slash and it should work.

Comment: Thanks the trailing slash made the difference for me

Comment: I had this exact issue doing Postman testing of logging in a Django Rest Framework API route. A JSON POST was being interpreted as a GET because my test request was using HTTP instead of HTTPS. Thanks!